# Required DataBindingComponent is null in class AgentDetailsActivityBindingImpl

Tags: android, android-databinding

in my agent_details_activity.xml:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            app:agentImageUrl="@{item.url}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolBarContainer" />
```

in activity:

```
class AgentDetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: AgentDetailsActivityBinding

    companion object {
        val AGENT_DETAILS = AgentDetailsActivity::class.java.name + "_AGENT_DETAILS"
    }

    private val TAG = AgentDetailsActivity::class.java.name

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = AgentDetailsActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.setHandler(this);
    }

  @BindingAdapter("agentImageUrl")
    fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {
        Glide.with(view.context)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .apply(RequestOptions().error(R.drawable.no_image))
            .into(view)
    }
```

but in runtime I get error:

```
Shutting down VM
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.android.testproject.android.kotlin.debug, PID: 24924
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.testproject.android.kotlin.debug/com.android.testproject.android.kotlin.coroutine_retrofit.ui.activity.AgentDetailsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required DataBindingComponent is null in class AgentDetailsActivityBindingImpl. A BindingAdapter in com.android.testproject.android.kotlin.coroutine_retrofit.ui.activity.AgentDetailsActivity is not static and requires an object to use, retrieved from the DataBindingComponent. If you don't use an inflation method taking a DataBindingComponent, use DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent or make all BindingAdapter methods static.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required DataBindingComponent is null in class AgentDetailsActivityBindingImpl. A BindingAdapter in com.android.testproject.android.kotlin.coroutine_retrofit.ui.activity.AgentDetailsActivity is not static and requires an object to use, retrieved from the DataBindingComponent. If you don't use an inflation method taking a DataBindingComponent, use DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent or make all BindingAdapter methods static.
    at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.ensureBindingComponentIsNotNull(ViewDataBinding.java:666)
    at com.android.testproject.android.kotlin.databinding.AgentDetailsActivityBindingImpl.<init>(AgentDetailsActivityBindingImpl.java:40)
    at com.android.testproject.android.kotlin.databinding.AgentDetailsActivityBindingImpl.<init>(AgentDetailsActivityBindingImpl.java:32)
    at com.android.testproject.android.kotlin.DataBinderMapperImpl.getDataBinder(DataBinderMapperImpl.java:52)
    at androidx.databinding.MergedDataBinderMapper.getDataBinder(MergedDataBinderMapper.java:74)
    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bind(DataBindingUtil.java:199)
    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:130)
    at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.inflateInternal(ViewDataBinding.java:1366)
    at com.android.testproject.android.kotlin.databinding.AgentDetailsActivityBinding.inflate(AgentDetailsActivityBinding.java:95)
    at com.android.testproject.android.kotlin.databinding.AgentDetailsActivityBinding.inflate(AgentDetailsActivityBinding.java:81)
    at com.android.testproject.android.kotlin.coroutine_retrofit.ui.activity.AgentDetailsActivity.onCreate(AgentDetailsActivity.kt:37)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
```

Comment: bind adapter method must be static

Comment: I wrote a detailed answer below to understand the main reason of this error also provided the possible best solutions there

Answer (score 30):

To elaborate on @mahdi shahbazi answer (The bind adapter method must be static):

In kotlin, place your binding method outside of any class (so in your case oustide of the Activity class). This will do the trick. In your case, it will look like:

```
@BindingAdapter("agentImageUrl")
fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {
    Glide.with(view.context)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .apply(RequestOptions().error(R.drawable.no_image))
        .into(view)
}

class AgentDetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: AgentDetailsActivityBinding

    companion object {
        val AGENT_DETAILS = AgentDetailsActivity::class.java.name + "_AGENT_DETAILS"
    }

    private val TAG = AgentDetailsActivity::class.java.name

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = AgentDetailsActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.setHandler(this);
    }

    ...

}
```

I have been able to come up with this answer thanks to this article: https://proandroiddev.com/custom-attributes-using-bindingadapters-in-kotlin-971ef8fcc259.
There are lots of other good tips in it, I recommend looking into it for yummies about view binding.

Comment: if as in my case the binding adapter is supposed to be in the ViewModel, it works to put it outside the class clause too.

Comment: Solution worked for me is - `place your binding method outside of any class`

Answer (score 30):

In my case I found a really simple method, I had the same error as you. I just had to add `@JvmStatic` annotation.

**The code will look something like this:**

```
companion object {

     @JvmStatic // add this line !!
     @BindingAdapter("agentImageUrl")
        fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {
            Glide.with(view.context)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .apply(RequestOptions().error(R.drawable.no_image))
                .into(view)
        }
}
```

Comment: Placing the @BindingAdapter method outside any class also works and this one also worked, but this one is more understandable and kotliny solution. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Yes, first of all place your binding method outside of any class.
Second, make `imageUrl` nullable! Because if the `imageUrl` becomes `null` anytime, you will get crash before `onError()` is invoked.

```
@BindingAdapter("agentImageUrl")
fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String?) {
    Glide.with(view.context)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .apply(RequestOptions().error(R.drawable.no_image))
        .into(view)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
@BindingAdapter("android:loadImage")
fun loadImage(userImageView: ImageView, imageUrl: String): Unit {
    Glide
        .with(userImageView)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .into(userImageView)
}
```

This is my **solution**, I have written my `function` outside the `class`

Answer (score 3):

for me nesting method inside companion object{} and adding @JvmStatic worked.

```
companion object{
            @JvmStatic
            @BindingAdapter("avatarBinder")
            fun loadAvatar(view: ImageView, avatar: String?):Unit{
                    Glide.with(view.context)
                            .load(avatar).into(view);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. add this annotation `@JvmStatic`
2. make all variables **nullable**

   `imageUrl:String` will be `imageUrl:String?`

solution will be

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("agentImageUrl")
fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String?) {
    Glide.with(view.context)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .apply(RequestOptions().error(R.drawable.no_image))
        .into(view)
}
```

Comment: In that case your `@BindingAdapter` declaration must be in a `static field` like you should declare them inside `companion object`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this bug , when I mistakenly added this binderAdapters inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of declaring all `@BindingAdapter`s in a single app. Either they should be declared in any `Static` field or in any `Global Scope` like outside of `Activity` or `Fragment` file or  you can gather all `@BindingAdapter`s in a single file and make that file `DefaultComponent` for `Data Binding`. The last approach is the more architectural way of declaring all `@BindingAdapter`s in a single app.

**Let's discuss both approaches here:**

**Simple way:** Create a file anywhere in the project and declare all `@BindingAdapter`s in a single `companion object` inside that file like following:

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("agentImageUrl")
    fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String?) {
        Glide.with(view.context)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .apply(RequestOptions().error(R.drawable.no_image))
            .into(view)
    }
}
```

> Do not forget to declare all the `@BindingAdapter`s as `@JvmStatic`

> You can also declare your `@BindingAdapter`s outside of your `Activity` or `Fragment` which is a `Global Scope`, that will also solve the error but there might be a risk that you may write same `@BindingAdapter` in multiple places in a single project.

**Architectural way:** This is the best approach to declare all `@BindingAdapter`s in a single project.

1. First create a `file` and declare a `class` not `companion object` in this case and declare all `@BindingAdapter`s inside this `class` like following:

   ```
   class BindingAdapters {
       @BindingAdapter(value = ["imageUrl", "imageRequestListener"], requireAll = false)
       fun bindImage(imageView: ImageView, url: String?, listener: RequestListener<Drawable?>?) {
           Glide.with(imageView.context)
               .load(url)
               .listener(listener)
               .into(imageView)
       }
   }
   ```

> Do not use `@JvmStatic` in this case

Create another `class` and extend `DataBindingComponent` class so that the compiler looks for binding components declaration in this file not elsewhere.

```
class AppDataBindingComponent : DataBindingComponent {
    private val adapter = BindingAdapters()
    override fun getBindingAdapters() = adapter
}
```

Finally add this following line inside the `onCreate()` function of your `Application` class

```
DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent(AppDataBindingComponent())
```

Like below:

```
class MainApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent(AppDataBindingComponent())
    }
}
```

That's it  now you can follow any of the above approach which seems easier to you.

> N.B: Do not forget to include your `Application` file inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` file like following:

```
<application
    android:name=".app.MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"/>
```

> Sorry for the long discussion but hope you will learn a lot from this discussion. Thank you